# Pivot out Rows into 7 Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to pivot out subordinate values relating to a main value.  I want to have seven SUB_VALX columns in the end.  I know I need to group by OB and VAL while pivoting out SUB_VAL based on other articles I have read. However, every answer I have seen creates multiple columns based on the SUB_VAL value. Here is my starting table:

**Starting Data**

```
----------------------
| OB | VAL | SUB_VAL |
----------------------
| 1  | 1   | NULL    |
| 2  | 2   | NULL    |
| 3  | 3   | 4       |
| 4  | 4   | NULL    |
| 5  | 6   | NULL    |
| 6  | 8   | 9       |
| 6  | 8   | 10      |
| 6  | 8   | 11      |
| 6  | 8   | 12      |
| 6  | 8   | 13      |
| 7  | 9   | 13      |
| 7  | 9   | 12      |
| 7  | 9   | 11      |
| 7  | 9   | 10      |
----------------------
```

I want to pivot out the rows in that table to form a table that looks like this:

**Starting Data**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| OB | VAL | SUB_VAL1 | SUB_VAL2 | SUB_VAL3 | SUB_VAL4 | SUB_VAL5 | SUB_VAL6 | SUB_VAL7 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| 2  | 2   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| 3  | 3   | 4        | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| 4  | 4   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| 5  | 6   | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
| 6  | 8   | 9        | 10       | 11       | 12       | 13       | NULL     | NULL     |
| 7  | 9   | 13       | 12       | 11       | 10       | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the code I adopted that creates over 128 columns when run (not what I am trying to accomplish):

```
DECLARE @Cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @DynSql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols + ', ', QUOTENAME(VAL))
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY VAL
ORDER BY VAL;

SET @DynSql = N'SELECT * 
FROM  
(
    SELECT OB, VAL, SUB_VAL
    FROM MyTable
) src
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(SUB_VAL) 
    FOR VAL IN (' + @Cols + N')
) pvt
ORDER BY OB';

-- SELECT @DynSql AS DynSql;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql;
```

Comment: Do you have a fixed maximum of 7 columns? And what are you using to determine the order? There is no way to produce the output you desire from your sample data because there is no way to order the rows.

Comment: @SeanLange yes there is a fixed maximum of 7 columns, as that is the maximum number of subordinate VALs possible for a VAL. Also order is not important. The SUB_VAL can be stored in SUB_VAL1, SUB_VAL2, etc in whatever order, as long as they are all there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a little while for me to grasp what you're trying to accomplish, but basically you want to have a list of a value associated with every OB and VAL pair.  If I am right, what you need to do is create some a result source that contains the position index of each value.  A window function is great for that.

The following will produce the result you want.  I am assuming that you're just using MAX in pivot as way to access the pivot functionality - the aggregation isn't necessary.  The column Key from the subquery is what you need to use to generate your column headers.  By using row_number I create a column index for each value associated to the OV, VAL pair.

You can adapt that subquery in code as both the source of data in your select to get column names as well as the subquery for src in your dynamic sql.  I present it to you this way so you can easily verify its correctness.

```
WITH testdata AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 1, null), (2, 2, null), (3, 3, 4), (4, 4, null), (5, 6, null), (6, 8, 9), (6, 8, 10),   
        (6, 8, 11), (6, 8, 12), (6, 8, 13), (7, 9, 13), (7, 9, 12), (7, 9, 11), (7, 9, 10)
    ) x ( [OB],[VAL],[SUB_VAL] )
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT OB, VAL, SUB_VAL
        , 'SUB_VAL' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OB, VAL ORDER BY SUB_VAL) AS VARCHAR(10)) [ColKey]
    FROM testdata
) src
PIVOT
(
    MAX(SUB_VAL)
    FOR [ColKey] IN (SUB_VAL1,SUB_VAL2,SUB_VAL3,SUB_VAL4,SUB_VAL5,SUB_VAL6,SUB_VAL7)
) pvt
ORDER BY OB, VAL
```

Here is the adaptation to your original query to produce the dynamic sql:

```
SELECT @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols + ', ', QUOTENAME(ColKey))
FROM (
    SELECT OB, VAL, SUB_VAL SUB_VAL
         , 'SUB_VAL' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OB, VAL ORDER BY SUB_VAL) AS VARCHAR(10)) [ColKey]
    FROM MyTable
) src
GROUP BY ColKey;

SET @DynSql = N'SELECT * 
FROM  
(
    SELECT OB, VAL, SUB_VAL SUB_VAL
         , ''SUB_VAL'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OB, VAL ORDER BY SUB_VAL) AS VARCHAR(10)) [ColKey]
    FROM MyTable
) src
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(SUB_VAL) 
    FOR ColKey IN (' + @Cols + N')
) pvt
ORDER BY OB';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql
```

Comment: Thank you, and I apologize if the question was worded awkwardly. Your assumption about using MAX to access the pivot function is correct.Let me give this a try in my data.